# Stop bouncing at start/end of webpage (OS X)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bounce

When I scroll when I'm at the start or end of a webpage I get a bounce effect (only on OS X), but that's not the case on for example [www.icloud.com/](https://www.icloud.com/)
Is there a code to "turn this off" for my website like on the iCloud site?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes.. my question is if there's a code to turn the bouncing off on my website. So not in my browser settings or something.

Comment: Not sure why people are voting this down or voting to close... It's a perfectly legitimate question, especially when a site has been provided that demonstrates the desired functionality.

Comment: If you solve your own question, you should post the solution as an answer then accept your own answer. This allows the question to be marked as answered so it won't appear in lists of unsolved questions.

Comment: "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." - I'll do that in six hours :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This did it for me.](http://www.smilingsouls.net/Blog/20110804114957.html?hSearchCursor=1/2/1#hFileComments) The secret is "overflow: hidden".